# how to set english as default language when changing language in settings?

Tags: flutter, localization, intl

How can I set the default language to English if I changed the language in the settings

[image]

in this case, I do not have the first language localized, but the other two are localized

therefore, I will always have a second language by default, but I want only English in any such situations

that is, if my language is not localized, I want it to be English instead

i used https://pub.dev/packages/intl library

Answer (score 2):

```
return const MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
  supportedLocales: List.from(AppLocalizations.supportedLocales)..sort((a, b) => b.languageCode == "en" ? 1 : 0),
  home: MyHomePage(),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a locale property inside the material app , your can set it to your default language

```
locale: _locale,

Locale _locale = const Locale('en', '');
```

Comment: Yes, it really works, but I want that when I change the language that I localized, for example Russian, Russian is displayed